# how to know if item in listview is pressed/geting listview item from id

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have populated a list view. which show up like

```
123 apple
456 Linux
789 windows
```

I have also added onItemClick listener to it and by displaying toast I can check the id of pressed listview. As I have a long list of approx. 1000 items, I want that if item 1 is clicked I should get the listview. some thing like

```
String clicked_Item = 123 apple.
```

how can I do it. here is my itm listener.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long id) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item clicked id="+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter, you should have a method called `getItem(position)`
So, in your onItemClickListener, the `int arg2` means the position of the list that was clicked.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long id) {
        Object object = adapter.getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item clicked id="+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

So, this object might be your model, wich means  that this object has every information you want. So, just take what you want.

Comment: so if I do so will it display the string/data at that particular position?

Comment: Yeap, because the arg2 parameter means the position in the listview which was pressed. So, in your adapter you can have this item especifcally